# I could'nt get content when change location of infinispan.xml

Tags: infinispan

First ,it works well when the config is :
`<property name="location" value="./files/store"/>`
But could't get anything when I changed it to
`<property name="location" value="~/tem/files/store/"/>`
and copy all the files to **~/tem/files**

why?

Comment: Have you tried using your full directory name? e.g. `/home/foo/tem/files/store/`? And we would also need to know more about your deployment model - are you using WildFly, Spring Boot, other?

Comment: ~ is not right .  needing to change to "/home/xxxx"

Answer (score 0):

Support for relative file store paths is not available yet. However, I've created [an issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-8486) to track your issue and I already have a fix for it which I'll submit in the next few minutes.